# Rewrite a perticular URL in .htaccess file not based on pattern

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to rewrite a single URL of my website (Joomla) to a friendly URL i.e.

`www.example.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=article&id=10&nav_button=0&article_layout=1&Itemid=503`

to

`www.example.com/favourit`

without disturbing the other URLs of the website

Thank you for your help.

Comment: will data change in this URL? I mean if you directly redirect it to `favorite` and `itemid` changed to 504 than what should it will do?

Comment: URL will not going to change, if I type `www.example.com/favourit` it should display the data which is being displayed in the above shown lengthy URL

Comment: then below answer is correct just put as it is in your htaccess and /favourit will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original question:**

Try

```
RewriteRule ^favourit$ /index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=article&id=10&nav_button=0&article_layout=1&Itemid=503 [L]
```

**OP springs a sub folder..**

If you intend to move the site live, as `example.com` presumes your already live but your comment suggests your still working on `localhost` then you should.

Put in the webroot thats `/` not `/mysite`

```
RewriteRule ^mysite/favourit$ /mysite/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=article&id=10&nav_button=0&article_layout=1&Itemid=503 [L]
```

**This is temporary so you don't need to fix once you go live.**

Comment: Yes I have tried the same but getting error,
Not Found

The requested URL /mysite/favourit was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: So its got `/mysite` prefixed? then use RewriteRule ^mysite/favourit$ ...

Comment: `http://localhost/mysite/` this is the main directory of my site in my local and this is how I want to access the friendly URL `http://localhost/mysite/favourit`, I have tried this `^mysite/favourit$` but still same issue

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question lol, my answer answers your original question.

Comment: I have tried the above code but still getting same error message

Comment: can you update your question with the `.htaccess` contents which is *getting same error message* and explain more what you done.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^favourit$ index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=article&id=179&nav_button=0&article_layout=1&Itemid=503 [L]`

is showing the content of Home page (i.e.: index.php) content of the full url is not showing